# How do you enforce password complexity rules in Zotonic?

Tags: zotonic

I would like to enforce a password policy in Zotonic.  My first impression would be to do this as a validator on the `new_password` field in the Identity editor.

Here is an example policy:

- Have be at least 8 characters in length
- Have at least one upper case letter
- Have at least one lower case letter
- Have at least one number
- Have at least one non-alphanumeric character
- Not be based on account name

Here is a possible implementation (not tested):

```
string:length(Password) >= 8 andalso
re:run(Password, "[A-Z]") =/= nomatch andalso
re:run(Password, "[a-z]") =/= nomatch andalso
re:run(Password, "[0-9]") =/= nomatch andalso
re:run(Password, "[^A-Za-z0-9]") =/= nomatch andalso
re:run(Password, AccountName) =:= nomatch
```

How do you enforce password complexity rules in Zotonic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is implement it as a form validation. Along the lines of the other validations.

I was wondering if there is a javascript available that shows the password strength.  (Like a traffic light, green ok, red really not ok.)

The validation can be attached using the `{% validate %}` scomp.

A simple password check could be done by making a single regular expression and attaching it to the password field using the `format` validator  http://zotonic.com/documentation/634/format

For your proposed function, or a "traffic light" functionality, it might be better to make a custom validator. Or that we add support for the Custom validator of LiveValidation, to which you then pass a Javascript function for the check.

Comment: There are a few JavaScript password checkers I have found without a graphical output. http://www.geekwisdom.com/dyn/passwdmeter is the best of those.  Using its output to drive a graphical quality meter should be straight-forward.  I will take a crack at it now.

Comment: http://phiras.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/password-strength-meter-v-2/ is much better and JQuery based as well.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague pointed me to:

```
^.*(?=.{10,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$
```

A full explanation is available from the original author at http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2004/09/25/501.aspx.

It has a slight bug when used in Zotonic (probably due to weirdness in the re module) so I changed the `\d` to `[0-9]` and reduced the required length to 8:

```
^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$
```

It can be applied in `_action_dialog_set_username_password.tpl` by replacing the **presence** validator:

```
{% validate id="new_password" type={presence} %}
```

with a **format** validator as ***Marc W*** describes in [How do you enforce password complexity rules in Zotonic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864903/how-do-you-enforce-password-complexity-rules-in-zotonic/3866181#3866181):

```
{% validate id="new_password" type={format pattern="^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$"} %}
```